# Linux: is it possible to create instruction to check if connection between 2 hosts is possible?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, telnet, multicast

I am running some software which is deployed on two different hosts.Hosts communicate via network. Linux is used on both. They use special port for communication. Also Multicast can be used.

A question is:

**How can I create an instruction for users to make sure that there are no network problems between these two hosts?**

The simplest thing I can imagine is to ask them to use "ping , if it fails - go to admin". Ok, but there are so many other cases to check. Check if the port we need is open, check if multicast is possible, may be some check with telnet? How can I perform it?

So could you please give some check list to do basing on your experience?

Comment: Look at [nagios](https://www.nagios.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the users are knowledgeable about Linux (Are they?), they can user the terminal to issue the non-privileged command referenced below.

ss is another utility to investigate sockets. See the MAN for more.

```
$ watch ss -tuna
```

They will see ESTABlished connections, among other connections, between the various hosts.

```
tcp    ESTAB      0      0          10.100.71.131:33785      10.100.71.22:445
tcp    ESTAB      0      0          10.100.71.131:47411      10.100.71.12:445
tcp    ESTAB      0      0          10.100.71.131:47410      10.100.71.12:445
tcp    ESTAB      0      0          10.100.71.131:22        10.100.71.142:57357
tcp    ESTAB      0      0          10.100.71.131:34088      10.100.71.11:445
tcp    ESTAB      0      0          10.100.71.131:44328      10.100.71.21:445
```

There are many other options; e.g., mtr google.com; which is a non-privileged network diagnostic tool that will provide info that just a ping.

Answer (score -2):

Why are you asking for users to check if your services are running? Set up a monitoring system (Zabbix for example) and problem solved.

Comment: This is a comment.  Comments should never be submitted as an answer to a question.   You suggested software that could do the job, but offered no specifics, on how to configure it so it does the job